# OnClick pass url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, parameter-passing

This is my very first question here after looking for many hours.

I have a button:

```
<a class="btn" onclick="return filter('http://mysite/filter');">Filter</a>
```

That calls this little script:

```
<script language="javascript"> 

function filter(page)
{
    //alert('proceed filter!!');
    document.form.action = page;
    document.form.submit();
    return true;
}

</script>
```

Adapted from:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/664/Specifying-multiple-actions-from-a-single-Form

It all works actually, but the original post is from 2000 (13 years old)

So I was wondering if I should maybe update this code using jQuery.

I have the button with the URI I what to pass and submit.

I just don't know how to transform the javascript above to jQuery, if its at all necessary.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery? Because you've been told that inline handlers are bad? If so, jQuery is an easy way to not worry about browser differences and Caleb's answer is perfect. Also, your script tag should be `type="text/javascript"` without the `language` attribute.

Comment: So you are asking **us** to go through your code and turn it into jQuery for you?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and for pointing out improvements and mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<a class="btn filter-btn" data-url="http://mysite/filter">Filter</a>

$('.filter-btn').on('click', function() {
  $('form').prop('action', $(this).attr('data-url')).submit(); // I recommend giving your form an ID or something instead of just matching on the form element.
});
```

With this approach you can have multiple `a.filter-btn`s each with their own `data-url` and the code to process it lives in one place and not in many different `onclick`s.

Comment: Thank you very much Caleb! Its working perfectly. I did follow your suggestion and added ID to form and button. Now I can make this reusable all over my website. Cheers